# Driver variables not updating using custom functions

Tags: python, drivers

I'm making an addon (in Blender 2.8 final release), in which I have a custom function on a driver and I want that function to change the value of some properties of different objects (like their location, rotation or scale).
If I do that directly, the value in the property window changes, but not in the viewport!

I also tried making the function control a custom property (I'm using dictionaries, but the problem exist also with normal custom properties) and then creating a driver on those properties that have that custom property as variable, but it works even less.

Here I wrote a simple case of what I mean:

```
import bpy

def test(self):
    empty = bpy.data.objects["Empty"]
    obj = bpy.data.objects["Cube"]
    value = empty.location[0]

    # 1 - try to change location[1] directly: the value in the Property panel change, but the viewport doesn't update
    obj.location[1] = value

    # 2 - change a custom property, then use a driver on location[0] that points to that custom property, 
    #but the driver doesn't update (even using the "Update dependancies" button)
    bpy.data.objects["propHolder"]["item"] = value   

    #the method I used in blender 2.79 to update the obj driver (now it seems to have no effect)
    for driv in obj.animation_data.drivers:
            driv.driver.expression += " "
            driv.driver.expression = driv.driver.expression[:-1]

    return 0

bpy.app.driver_namespace["test"] = test
```

and [here you can download a simple .blend file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1J6FzTcW5zdMKP2CkIYKLFTshlgsjEl0k/view?usp=sharing) as an example.

---

I know that a modal timer operator is a solution, but the addon to be responsive should have a refresh rate higher than ~10 Herz (10 times per second), which could make Blender quite slow in big projects

Also, I could create a driver for every affected property, but that would mean that all the drivers have to make all the calculations, which would slow Blender down and create a lot of clutter in the project

Comment: This appears to be a horrible abuse of the driver system, lol.  If the driver is on "Cube" then `self` is "Cube".  You are not using it.  For `Cube.location.x`  There is a driver on location.x and you are setting  that property value in the driver as well as from the driver. return value. it's quite confusing   It's also why you are getting the "Can't edit driven number value, see graph editor for the driver setup." message in the info window.  Could you please articulate what the desired result of this set up is?

Comment: Sure. In my addon I have a master object and every time it changes position scale or rotation i need to calculate the value of many other properties. Setting up a driver that calculate his own value for every of those properties is a mess (expecially because usually not all of those properties are affected), and can cause Blender to slow down (because it has more calculations to make). So I want to use a function to make all the calculations at once and then assign the calculated values to all the affected objects and properties. I don't have that error in the Info window.

Comment: And sorry, I know that 'self' is the Cube, but I made that project quickly and I didn't think about it.

Comment: for the location.x comment: in the little example script I tried 2 methods to change the value of location.x and location.y (to see what the different methods output was) of the cube given the location.x of the empty. The first method is to change the value of location.y from the function itself, the second is to output the calculated value (in the example there are not calculations, but still) to a custom property and then use a driver on the location.x of the cube that reads that custom poperty ('"item"'). The last one is horrible, but still faster than a driver for each property